# How can I decompose strings and append its characters in order?

Tags: python, string

I have this:

```
word = 'abcd'
```

And I want this:

```
do_something(word)

>>['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
word = 'abcd'

def do_something(word):
    return [word[:x + 1] for x in xrange(len(word))]

print do_something(word)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']
```

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
[word[:i] for i in xrange(len(word))]
```

Comment: This gives {'', 'a', 'ab', 'abc'] instead of ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']

Comment: Also it is better to use xrange instead of range because it prevents the creation of an array instead of an iterator.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers i think an off-by-1 error is something the OP should be able to notice/fix on his own, i accept the comment about xrange though.

Comment: true ... that's why I haven't downvoted your answer. It's only meant as remark, not as offense in any way.